# XPATH - how to query node based on sibling attributes/data?

Tags: xpath

```
...More <book></book> objects here

<book>
  <author>John</author>
  <price>50</price>
</book>

<book>
  <author>Henry</author>
  <price>60</price>
</book>
... More <book></book> objects here
```

I want to get the `price` value of the book with author `John`

This is my failed attempt `//book//[self::author//text()="john"].//price`

What is the right query to get this `price` detail?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this way:

```
//book[author= 'John']/price/text()
```

this will return : `50`

I f you want to get the price element, you should use the following expression:

```
//book[author= 'John']/price
```

it returns : `<price>50</price>`

notice that XML is case sensitive. so, `john` and `John` are different values.

Answer (score -2):

I used this site to test some xpaths out. [Xpath Tester](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath)  seems //book//price worked fine to return the price.

Comment: The OP wants to get the `price` value of the book with author `John`.